# How to get desired coordinates with known static_tf?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, tf2, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[image: image description]

Hi, according to the attached picture I have a base link (point 1) with 0 coordinates. Then, I know the coordinates of the point 2 relative to point 1 frame. Also I have a static_tf from point 3 to point 2 relative to point 3 coordinate frame (blue numbers = z offset).

My question is: how to find coordinates of the point 3 relative to the base link?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/367035/how-to-get-desired-coordinates-with-known-static_tf?/) by [Jericho](https://answers.ros.org/users/56491/jericho/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-12-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The transform tree keeps track of the relationship between frames, including static transforms, which you can view with `rosrun rqt_tf_tree rqt_tf_tree`.  To access the data, there are multiple methods depending on how you want to read/use the results:

- The [tf2 intro tutorial](https://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials/Introduction%20to%20tf2) explains how to view a transform from the command line: `rosrun tf tf_echo [reference_frame] [target_frame]`
- The [tf2 listener (C++)](https://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf2%20listener%20%28C%2B%2B%29) and [tf2 listener (Python)](https://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf2%20listener%20%28Python%29) tutorials explain how to get the transform in your own node.

If you have questions that are not answered by the tutorials, please, feel free to clarify.

---

###Answer Part 2

Yes, `tf2` enables you to transform many data types into a frame of your choosing.  As [this answer](https://answers.ros.org/question/324774/how-to-use-tf2-to-transform-posestamped-messages-from-one-frame-to-another/?answer=324853#post-id-324853) explains, you can use the [`tfBuffer::transform()` function](https://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/tf2_ros/html/c++/classtf2__ros_1_1BufferInterface.html#a6674f53992999da887a22e54467cba0b).  If you have a pose as a `PoseStamped` message in `base_frame` but want it in `other_frame`, after appropriate setup, you can do something like (C++)

```
tf_buffer.transform(pose_in_base_frame, pose_in_other_frame, "other_frame");
```

or (Python)

```
pose_in_other_frame = tf_buffer.transform(pose_in_base_frame, "other_frame")
```

[Here's an answer](https://answers.ros.org/question/249433/tf2_ros-buffer-transform-pointstamped/) that deals with transforming a `PointStamped` message in Python for additional info.

If all you have are values (not an actual message), you can insert those values into a new message first.

---

Originally posted by [tryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33908/tryan/) with karma: 1421 on 2020-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jericho](https://answers.ros.org/users/56491/jericho/) on 2020-12-06**:
Thanks for your answer, I actually do have one question. I have a desired pose relative to base (just a set of 6 values xyzrpy) and I need to calculate tf from some other than base frame. Is there a possibility to not firstly broadcast this pose as tf and then subscribe? Can I just, having these 6 values in my code, calculate a tf right there using tf libraries?

**Comment by [tryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33908/tryan/) on 2020-12-07**:
Future readers, see Answer Part 2, added to my original answer above.